# DNS debian SERVFAIL server can't find, no ping

Tags: dns, debian, bind, nslookup

I'm trying create a DNS server in my environment of test, but i don't know bind. The settings from my server is created with result of search in google. The bind start without error, but don't resolve my domain. I'm trying create a domain: **lunarinterativa.labs** to use in my solutions.

i receive this error:

```
server can't find www.lunarinterativa.labs.lunarinterativa.labs: SERVFAIL
```

when i execute the command below:

```
nslookup
> server interativa32
Default server: interativa32
Address: 172.224.116.100#53
> www.lunarinterativa.labs
Server:         interativa32
Address:        172.224.116.100#53
```

My internal netwotk settings is:

```
ip address: 172.224.116.100
netmask: 255.255.255.0
gateway: 172.224.116.254
```

I ping to interativa32.lunarinterativa.labs: is OK

```
PING interativa32.lunarinterativa.labs (172.224.116.100) 56(84) bytes of data.64 bytes from interativa32.lunarinterativa.labs (172.224.116.100): icmp_req=1 ttl=64 time=0.049 ms
```

I ping to www.interativa32.lunarinterativa.labs: is Wrong

```
ping: unknown host www.interativa32.lunarinterativa.labs
```

This is the content of file of settings from my domain (file: /etc/bind/db.lunarinterativa.labs) :

```
; -------------------------------------------------------------------
; Created by Lunar Interativa Scripts
; type: Bind9
; author: Sileno de Oliveira Brito
; since: 09 Mar 2013
; created: 10 Mar 2013
; domain: lunarinterativa.labs
; ip address: 172.224.116.100
; hostname: interativa32
; -------------------------------------------------------------------
$TTL   604800
@       IN      SOA     interativa32.lunarinterativa.labs.      root.interativa32.lunarinterativa.labs. (
                        2004111700  ; Serial
                        604800          ; Refresh
                        86400           ; Retry
                        2419200     ; Expire
                        604800 )    ; Negative Cache TTL
;
@       IN      A                               172.224.116.100

interativa32            IN      A       172.224.116.100
www                     IN      CNAME   @
ftp                     IN      CNAME   @
repo                    IN      CNAME   @
ns1                     IN      CNAME   @
```

This is the content of file of settings from my reverse domain (file: /etc/bind/db.lunarinterativa.labs):

```
; -------------------------------------------------------------------
; Created by Lunar Interativa Scripts
; type: Bind9 Reverse
; author: Sileno de Oliveira Brito
; since: 09 Mar 2013
; created: 10 Mar 2013
; domain: lunarinterativa.labs
; reverse: 116.224.172.in-addr.arpa
; ip address: 172.224.116.100
; hostname: interativa32
; -------------------------------------------------------------------
@       IN      SOA     interativa32.lunarinterativa.labs.      root.interativa32.lunarinterativa.labs. (
                        2004111700  ; Serial
                        604800          ; Refresh
                        86400           ; Retry
                        2419200     ; Expire
                        604800 )    ; Negative Cache TTL
@       IN      NS                              ns.lunarinterativa.labs.
@       IN      A                               172.224.116.100
100     IN      PTR     interativa32.lunarinterativa.labs
```

This is the entry in /etc/bind/named.conf.local

```
zone "116.224.172.in-addr.arpa" {
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/db.116.224.172.in-addr.arpa";
};
zone "lunarinterativa.labs" {
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/db.lunarinterativa.labs";
};
```

This is my /etc/resolv.conf

```
domain lunarinterativa.labs
search lunarinterativa.labs
nameserver 127.0.0.1
```

This is my /etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
172.224.116.100 interativa32.lunarinterativa.labs       interativa32

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

This is my /etc/bind/named.conf.options

```
options {
        directory "/var/cache/bind";

        // If there is a firewall between you and nameservers you want
        // to talk to, you may need to fix the firewall to allow multiple
        // ports to talk.  See http://www.kb.cert.org/vuls/id/800113

        // If your ISP provided one or more IP addresses for stable
        // nameservers, you probably want to use them as forwarders.
        // Uncomment the following block, and insert the addresses replacing
        // the all-0's placeholder.

        forwarders {
                8.8.8.8;
        //      0.0.0.0;
                172.224.116.254;
        };

        auth-nxdomain no;    # conform to RFC1035
        listen-on port 53 { 127.0.0.1; 172.224.116.100; };
        allow-query { 127.0.0.1; 172.224.116.0/24; };
        allow-recursion { 127.0.0.1; 172.224.116.0/24; };
        allow-transfer { none; };

        listen-on-v6 { any; };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is in my file of configuration i found in web a script and see my error.

This is the correct content of file of settings from my domain (file: /etc/bind/db.lunarinterativa.labs) :

```
; -------------------------------------------------------------------
; Created by Lunar Interativa Scripts
; type: Bind9
; author: Sileno de Oliveira Brito
; credit: OLIVEIRA , Willian:CONFIGURAÃO APACHE E DNS (BIND). Viva o Linux, DisponÃ­l em: http://www.vivaolinux.com.br/script/Configuracao-Apache-e-DNS-(bind), Acesso em 10/03/2012 Ã 20h 00min
; since: 09 Mar 2013
; created: 10 Mar 2013
; domain: labs.lunarinterativa
; ip address: 172.224.116.100
; hostname: interativa32
; -------------------------------------------------------------------
$TTL   604800
@       IN      SOA     labs.lunarinterativa.   root.labs.lunarinterativa. (
                        2004111700  ; Serial
                        604800          ; Refresh
                        86400           ; Retry
                        2419200     ; Expire
                        604800 )    ; Negative Cache TTL
;
@       IN      NS                              labs.lunarinterativa.
@       IN      A                               172.224.116.100

interativa32            IN      A       172.224.116.100
www                     IN      CNAME   interativa32.labs.lunarinterativa.
ftp                     IN      CNAME   interativa32.labs.lunarinterativa.
repo                    IN      CNAME   interativa32.labs.lunarinterativa.
ns1                     IN      CNAME   interativa32.labs.lunarinterativa.
```

This is the correct content of file of settings from my reverse domain (file: /etc/bind/db.lunarinterativa.labs):

```
; -------------------------------------------------------------------
; Created by Lunar Interativa Scripts
; type: Bind9 Reverse
; author: Sileno de Oliveira Brito
; since: 09 Mar 2013
; created: 10 Mar 2013
; domain: labs.lunarinterativa
; reverse: 116.224.172.in-addr.arpa
; ip address: 172.224.116.100
; hostname: interativa32
; -------------------------------------------------------------------
@       IN      SOA     labs.lunarinterativa.   root.labs.lunarinterativa. (
                        2004111700  ; Serial
                        604800          ; Refresh
                        86400           ; Retry
                        2419200     ; Expire
                        604800 )    ; Negative Cache TTL
@       IN      NS                              labs.lunarinterativa.
@       IN      A                               172.224.116.100
100     IN      PTR     interativa32.labs.lunarinterativa.
```

Responses:
nslookup to domain

```
nslookup www.labs.lunarinterativa
Server:         172.224.116.100
Address:        172.224.116.100#53
```

nslookup to ip reverse:

```
nslookup 172.224.116.100
Server:         172.224.116.100
Address:        172.224.116.100#53

100.116.224.172.in-addr.arpa    name = interativa32.labs.lunarinterativa.
```

Now the ping is ok.

To me understand the problem i used the script from Wiliam Oliveira available in http://www.vivaolinux.com.br/script/Configuracao-Apache-e-DNS-(bind)
one special thanks to he. Your scripts not have error in my enviroment.